# MySQL UPDATE one table with values from another table if they're not equal

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
SELECT
    d.id,
    d.permission_lookup_id,
    d.permission_object_id,
    f.id,
    f.permission_lookup_id,
    f.permission_object_id
FROM
    folders f
LEFT JOIN
    documents d
    ON f.id = d.folder_id
WHERE
    d.permission_lookup_id != f.permission_lookup_id OR
    d.permission_object_id != f.permission_object_id
```

In theory this should return nothing if all is well, but it isn't, I receive hundres of thousands of results (currently 407,343).  I need to update the `documents` table so that `permission_lookup_id` matches `folders`'s `permission_lookup_id` and likewise for `permission_object_id`, based off of `documents.parent_id` as the foreign key constraint.

I tried the following query with little success:

```
UPDATE 
    folders f
LEFT JOIN
    documents d
    ON f.id = d.folder_id
SET
    d.permission_lookup_id = f.permission_lookup_id,
    d.permission_object_id = f.permission_object_id
WHERE
    d.permission_lookup_id != f.permission_lookup_id OR
    d.permission_object_id != f.permission_object_id
```

After running that it tells me that 70,986 rows affected, and 407343 rows matched, yet I still have results from the first select query.

EDIT: Both of the following queries return 0 rows:

`SELECT * FROM folders WHERE permission_lookup_id IS NULL OR permission_object_id IS NULL;`

`SELECT * FROM documents WHERE permission_lookup_id IS NULL OR permission_object_id IS NULL;`

Same goes for blank values as well.

EDIT 2:  There was an amateur mistake made in my original select/update queries.  In the WHERE clause, I had:

```
WHERE
    d.permission_lookup_id != f.permission_lookup_id OR
    d.permission_object_id != f.permission_lookup_id
```

Where I should have had

```
WHERE
    d.permission_lookup_id != f.permission_lookup_id OR
    d.permission_object_id != f.permission_object_id
```

That was causing me to receive false positives, and merely would have caused nothing more than to have the updates go through and update every column regardless of whether or not it needed to.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is is possible that the `permission_lookup_id` from either table has NULL values?  If so, you might want to try using the NULL-safe operator:

```
WHERE
    (NOT d.permission_lookup_id <=> f.permission_lookup_id) OR
    (NOT d.permission_object_id <=> f.permission_lookup_id)
```

**UPDATE**

Try one field at time just to see and use the following syntax (this might take a longer to run):

```
UPDATE folders f
SET f.permission_lookup_id =COALESCE((SELECT d.permission_lookup_id FROM documents d
                                      WHERE f.id = d.folder_id
                                      AND d.permission_lookup_id != f.permission_lookup_id),
                                      f.permission_lookup_id)
```

Comment: Just checked, neither of the two tables have either `NULL` or blank values.

Comment: @Scott, Try checking/updating one field at a time.  Also, for your `SELECT` statement, use `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this alternative syntax:

```
UPDATE 
    folders f, documents d
SET
    d.permission_lookup_id = f.permission_lookup_id,
    d.permission_object_id = f.permission_object_id
WHERE
    f.id = d.folder_id AND (
    d.permission_lookup_id != f.permission_lookup_id OR
    d.permission_object_id != f.permission_lookup_id)
```

[The manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) says JOIN clauses are ok, but I'm curious to see if there's any difference.

> The preceding example shows an inner join that uses the comma
>   operator, but multiple-table UPDATE statements can use any type of
>   join permitted in SELECT statements, such as LEFT JOIN.

Comment: After running your query, I still have 407,343 rows remaining.

Comment: Thanks for giving it a try.  No rows updated in that case sounds a bit strange to me though; at the very least I would expect it to update the 70,986 you other query did.  Perhaps it will shed some light for the other folks trying to answer.

Comment: Actually, I stand corrected... I just took a closer look at the rows returned, and see that it's returning that number of rows, but the values match.  Manipulating your UPDATE query into a SELECT is returning the 407k rows, even if the `permission_lookup_id` and `permission_object_id` values match, so I'm uncertain at this point of how to check and see if it's an issue still.

Comment: Kind of an ugly suggestion, but can you just update the whole table regardless of difference, should get you moving at least and give you time to figure out what's up w/ the other queries?  `UPDATE folders f, documents d SET d.permission_lookup_id = f.permission_lookup_id, d.permission_object_id = f.permission_object_id;`

Comment: Actually, a really amateur mistake was made that was screwing up the selects and causing the updates to run repeatedly every time.  In the WHERE clause, the second clause read `d.permission_object_id != f.permission_lookup_id` where it should have read `d.permission_object_id != f.permission_object_id`.  It didn't break anything, just gave false positives and caused everything to update even if it was correct.  Amateur move, but shouldn't have broken anything... badly at least.

Comment: Is that what you had in there originally?  I'm pretty sure I just copied the original WHERE clause when writing my answer, but either way, a silly slip up.  Like I was saying though, worst case here, why not just update everything and call it a day, unless there's millions of rows or something, heh.

Comment: My apologies, I edited my original post after realizing the mistake, it was mine, not yours.

Answer (score 0):

Try using inner join in your query instead of left join and please let me know that whether your id field has null values? If yes, then it needs a different approach